# How to get python to only read the contents of a text file once

Tags: python, file, encryption, ascii

I am trying to figure out how to get Python to only read the contents of a .txt file once.  It is for a class project to encrypt and decrypt a message using all printable ASCII characters.  Doing it this way is not required.  This is only my fourth program I have written in Python and I really don't know what I am doing but I enjoy trying to come up with different ways to approach assignments.  I hope I have entered everything correctly on here.  I know this an easy fix, I just haven't been able to find the answer.  The assignment will be an ongoing project for the next 6 weeks.  My plan is to make the encryption much more complex (yes I know that you should never use Python for encryption).  So I am writing it with a bigger picture in mind.

That being said.  If anyone wants to go beyond answering my question, feel free to tear the entire thing apart.  Let me know what I've done wrong, why, how I could do it better.  I would love to get some feedback.

```py
import random
print("1. Encrypt")
print("2. Decrypt")
print(" ")

selection = int(input("What would you like to do? [1,2]? "))

while selection == 1:
    plainText = input('Enter the message you wish to encrypt: ')

    # right now the program encrypts the string at random between 1 and 95.  
    # All of the printable ASCII characters.
    # the code below is written for when I can take the parameters of 1-95
    # off and any input will simply loop around.
    distance = random.randint(1, 95)
    if distance < 1 or distance > 95:
        print('Try Again')
        continue
    else:

        # saves the random integer or (key) 
        # directly to a file without the user seeing it.

        f = open('..\\Desktop\\encryptPractice\\theKey.txt', 'w+')

        for key in range(1):
            number = distance
            f.write(str(number))

        f.close()

        code = ""

        for ch in plainText:
            ordvalue = ord(ch)
            ordvalue = ordvalue + distance

            while ordvalue < 32:
                ordvalue += 95
            while ordvalue > 126:
                ordvalue -= 95

            code += chr(ordvalue)

            # saves the encrypted message 
            # directly to a file without the user seeing it.

        f = open('..\\Desktop\\encryptPractice\\theMessage.txt', 'w+')

        for theMessage in range(1):
            secret = code
            f.write(str(secret))
        f.close()

        print('Your message has been saved to the file named theMessage.txt')
        break


# This is the decryption block - OPTION 
# 2.)*********************************************

while selection == 2:

    """
    I want to simply be able to open the file with the 'encrypted'
    message on it and then open the file with the 'key' on it and
    have the program decrypt the message and save it back to the
    same file.

    Both of the solutions below cause the program to read the
    'encrypted' message over and over and over and...you get it.
    """

    f = open('..Desktop\\encryptPractice\\theMessage.txt','r')
    for line in f:
        print(line)


    f = open('..Desktop\\encryptPractice\\theMessage.txt','r')
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line == ""
            break
        print(line)
```

Comment: Side note for beginners: Whoever told you *"you should never use Python for encryption"*, you probably have to check again whether you heard the person correctly or whether there are other context leading to that statement. Encryption can be implemented in any language. The problem with is not usually the language, but the implementation. Getting encryption right is not easy, so the more proper advice is "Use a well-reviewed and published encryption library (of the language of your choice) that is up-to-date and used by many, unless you are a cryptography professional writing your own."

Comment: Thank you for fixing my post and making it readable.  As to the Python encryption bit.  Perhaps I misunderstood.  Maybe it was something about not using 'Random' for encryption in python because it isn't truly random.  Great to know I was wrong though.  That means I can take this project even further than I thought.

Comment: There are fun little scripts/exercises you can write to learn about cryptography such as the ROT13 or Caesar cipher. When computing power was low, it was humanly possible to encrypt/decrypt by hand. For the current age of computing power, if we have anything sensitive to keep private for production use, usually we use stronger encryption such as the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA), DSA or the RSA with high bit (4096bit) for asymmetric encryption and libraries which perform such encryption. Symmetric encryption there is Diffie–Hellman key exchange underneath your web browser.

Comment: For the point on "random". This is a topic on entropy, which is more deeply mathematical on the measure on how random each random function generator is. There are pseudo-random generators, which when seeded properly, will give you the same result every time you run it, which means it is predictable, which means it is not random, which in turn means a pattern can be traced and your encryption can be broken. And pseudo-random is mostly the norm in many libraries, even hardware-generated random numbers, unless it uses some radioactive half-life decay measurement of atomic particles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand your code because it's not indented properly. But here's my guess: the lines `while selection == 1:` and `while selection == 2:` make the block of code run in a loop until the value of `selection` changes. If think you are looking for `if selection == 1:` and `if selection == 2:`.

Now a couple other comments about the code you shared:

- It's impossible for `distance` to be less than 1 or more than 95 because `randint(1, 95)` returns an integer in the range [1, 95].

```
distance = random.randint(1, 95)
if distance < 1 or distance > 95:                                   
    print('Try Again')                                              
    continue
```

- You are using a `for` loop that iterates over a sequence of size 1 (`range(1)`):

```
for theMessage in range(1):
    secret = code
    f.write(str(secret))
```

This block can be reduced to `f.write(str(code))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  @Vken cleaned up my post for me.  My issue right now is getting python to read the contents of a file only once.  I want the 'Decrypt' section of the program to pull the information from the files it saved in the 'Encrypt' section.  I can't figure out how to get it to only read the string in the .txt file once.  Right now it reads the string in an endless loop.

Comment: You were correct about the while loop.  Sorry I didn't understand what you were saying the first time.  On the plus side I know a hundred different ways to pull data from a file and structure it now.  Thank you.

Comment: No worries! Glad you figured it out